# How to add horizontal line in a table?

Tags: html, css

Following is the code of table :

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="" width="100%" border="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="pack_list_divider">
      <td width="30%" rowspan="2">
        <img id="coursimg" src="test_listings_files/default_package_image.png" alt="Section wise test" border="0">
      </td>
      <td width="25%">
        <p class="pckgvalidity">
          Validity : 1 Year&nbsp;
        </p>
      </td>
      <td width="35%">
        <p class="pckgvalidity">Number of Tests : 0
        </p>
      </td>
      <td width="20%" valign="middle">
        <!--<p id="test_list_loader" height="20" align="center" style="display:none;"></p> -->
        <a href="http://localhost/abc/pqr/lmn/web/online-test-packages?op=get_package_detail&amp;test_pack_id=21e86b3ebf6a8af2a9fcf136c4f8e88a" class="view_test_package_details">Test Details</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" width="50%" valign="top">
        <p class="descp">
          sectionm wise tests
        </p>
      </td>
      <td width="20%">
        <p class="pckgrs"> <span class="rs fl" style="color:#333333; font:25px bold; margin:0px 0px 10px 10px;"> Free &nbsp; </span>
          <span> 
           <a class="user-not-loggedin more addcart fl" href="http://localhost/entrance_prime/Entrance_Prime/entprm/web/my_cart.php?pack_id=21e86b3ebf6a8af2a9fcf136c4f8e88a&amp;pack_type=test&amp;op=aa" id="21e86b3ebf6a8af2a9fcf136c4f8e88a" value="21e86b3ebf6a8af2a9fcf136c4f8e88a" style="background:url(../images_new/add_account.png) 0 0 no-repeat;">&nbsp;</a>             
           </span>
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I want a horizontal line in between the rows. I've tried so many tricks but none of them did the magic for me. How can this issue be resolved?

Comment: from here, that line seems to be a <hr/>.. try to add it into a tr td

Comment: I can't see a screen shot.

Answer (score 41):

I use this trick:

```html
<table>
  <tr style="border-bottom:1px solid black">
    <td colspan="100%"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr> ... </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: CSS in the TR element isn't always recognized - drop it in TD as a workaround.

Comment: Not visible in Chrome, Edge, FF, Opera. Did this ever work?

Answer (score 28):

Use a Table Header and add the underline in there

```css
table { border-collapse:collapse; }
table thead th { border-bottom: 1px solid #000; }
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Valididty></th>
      <th>No Of Tests</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

With CSS you can style the header row. Make each cell have a bottom border.

Comment: you also have to remove the cell spacing between the ths in order to have a continue border

Answer (score 18):

have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZmBmh/

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr class="firstLine">
        <td>hey</td><td>hello</td><td>yuhuu</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>hey</td><td>hello</td><td>yuhuu</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
          <td colspan="3"><hr/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>hey</td><td>hello</td><td>yuhuu</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
.firstLine td{
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<style>
  table {
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
</style>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Contents</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <td>
      <hr size="1px" color="black">
    </td>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Topic 1<br/> Topic 2<br/> Topic 3<br/> Topic 4<br/> Topic 5<br/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

</html>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Something like this:

```html
<table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="" width="100%">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="pack_list_divider">
      <tr> </tr>
      <td width="25%">
        <p class="pckgvalidity">
          Validity : 1 Year&nbsp;
        </p>
      </td>
      <td width="35%">
        <p class="pckgvalidity">Number of Tests : 0
        </p>
      </td>
      <td width="20%" valign="middle">
        <!--<p id="test_list_loader" height="20" align="center" style="display:none;"></p> -->
        <a href="http://localhost/entrance_prime/Entrance_Prime/entprm/web/online-test-packages?op=get_package_detail&amp;test_pack_id=21e86b3ebf6a8af2a9fcf136c4f8e88a" class="view_test_package_details">Test Details</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td colspan="2" width="50%" valign="top">
        <p class="descp">
          sectionm wise tests
        </p>
      </td>
      <td width="20%">
        <p class="pckgrs"> <span class="rs fl" style="color:#333333; font:25px bold; margin:0px 0px 10px 10px;"> Free &nbsp; </span>
          <span> 
    
                    <a class="user-not-loggedin more addcart fl" href="http://localhost/entrance_prime/Entrance_Prime/entprm/web/my_cart.php?pack_id=21e86b3ebf6a8af2a9fcf136c4f8e88a&amp;pack_type=test&amp;op=aa" id="21e86b3ebf6a8af2a9fcf136c4f8e88a" value="21e86b3ebf6a8af2a9fcf136c4f8e88a" style="background:url(../images_new/add_account.png) 0 0 no-repeat;">&nbsp;</a>             
    
                 </span>

        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Tell me if that is what you're looking for.